# Can the plan-cache and/or statistics be copied from one instance to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, statistics, plan-cache

I restore production databases on top of a staging instance that I use for testing.

Is it possible to also copy the plan-cache and/or statistics to the staging instance, to better simulate the production environment for testing purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot copy individual plans form one server to another. You can [copy statistics](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914288/how-to-generate-a-script-of-the-necessary-database-metadata-to-create-a-statistics-only-database-in-sql-server) - generate script and run it on the test/staging env.

Mainly, you should focus on -

> Constraints, Statistics, Table size (number of rows and pages) and Database options along with sessions SET options and hardware resources (maxdop and max memory settings) inorder for the query optimizer to select a plan.

Alternatively, you can use plan guide for single queries.

Again, since you are on sql server 2008 R2, you cannot use query store or dbcc clone database.